# The Tomcat doesn't deploy my current my code changes

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

I have a problem with the dopleyement of my project Spring MVC through Tomcat Server.. I run my project I debug it but there is no change .. I clean the server and I clean the cache but no change it always deploy the previous version.

For example I have this line of code :

```
    String saveDirectory = "C://raexFile//";
```

And it give me a error that there is no directory RaexFile**s**  with s (my previous code version)

[It's deploy the version with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mionk.jpg)

Comment: Have you generated a new .war file?

Comment: no I don't know a lot about the .war but I just run it into tomcat with eclipse

Comment: war stands for Web ARchive, and is usually what the Tomcat environment runs. You will need to look up how to generate a new WAR file from the environment you are running.

Comment: When I show my project's properties I see as a workspace another path (my previous workspace) and as a time of last modification : 17 august 2017 it's like he run an previous instance of project and don't suppot the new modifications

Comment: Sounds like an Eclipse issue to me.